# puppet could not evaluate: could not retrieve information from environment

Tags: puppet

puppet can do exec on node, but cannot transfer file from module.

Ubuntu 14.04 server
Puppet 3.8.4

Already tried:

- making file world readable
- disabling FW
- creating facter.d in module directory

On master:

/etc/puppet/puppet.conf

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
node 'gitlab.domain' {
    include ssh
}
```

/etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp

```
class ssh {
  exec { 'apt-update':
    command => 'apt-get update',
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/bin', '/sbin'],
    logoutput => on_failure,
  }

  # ensure openssh installed
  package { 'openssh-server':
    ensure  => installed,
    require => Exec['apt-update'],
  }

  # make sure ssh keeps running
  service { 'ssh':
    ensure  => 'running',
    enable  => true,
    require => Package['openssh-server'],
  }


  # copy sshd_config
  file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config':
    ensure  => 'present',
    notify  => Service['ssh'],
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/ssh/config/sshd_config',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0600',
    require => Package['openssh-server'],
  }
}
```

On master:

```
ls -la /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/config
-rw-r--r-- 1 puppet root 356 Nov 27 11:43 sshd_config
```

On node:

```
sudo puppet agent -t -v
[....]
Info: Applying configuration version ...
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ssh/Exec[apt-update]/returns: executed successfully
Error: /Stage[main]/Ssh/File[/etc/ssh/sshd_config]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/ssh/config/sshd_config
```

Comment: Please run `sudo puppet agent -t -d` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Please provide the .`/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` that resides on the master and agent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is caused because `/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ssh/files/config/sshd_config` or `/etc/puppet/modules/ssh/files/config/sshd_config` does not exist