# puppet: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production

Tags: linux, puppet, puppetmaster

I have seen the similar post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/740030/puppet-could-not-evaluate-could-not-retrieve-information-from-environment), but that does not solve

Intent is to copy the bash script on agent node and execute.

```
SLES11SP4-118:~ # cat /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
node default {
   include base
}

node 'sles11sp4-170.dev.insiteone.com' {
 class {'base':}
}

class base {
   exec { "remove yum":
   command => 'zypper removerepo 1',
   logoutput => 'true',
   path    => '/usr/bin/'
   }

   exec { "add yum":
   command => 'zypper addrepo -f http://10.156.14.121/repo/RPMS/QA/ QA',
   logoutput => 'true',
   path    => '/usr/bin/'
   }

  file {
    'my_expect_script':
      ensure => 'present',
      source => "puppet:///modules/raj/myexpect.sh",
      path => '/tmp/',
      owner => 'root',
      group => 'root',
      mode  => '0744',
      notify => Exec['run_my_script'],
  }
  exec {
    'run_my_script':
     command => '/tmp/myexpect.sh',
     refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```

In /etc/puppet.conf

```
SLES11SP4-118:~ # vim /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
    dns_alt_names=puppet,puppet.dev.insiteone.com
    server=puppet.dev.insiteone.com
    modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules
```

I have made sure the directories are present in puppet server :

```
SLES11SP4-118:~ # puppet config print modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

SLES11SP4-118:~ # ls /etc/puppet/modules/raj/
myexpect.sh

SLES11SP4-118:~ # ls /usr/share/puppet/modules/raj/
myexpect.sh
```

Error (puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp --debug):

```
err: /Stage[main]/Base/File[my_expect_script]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/raj/myexpect.sh at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:31
notice: /Stage[main]/Base/Exec[run_my_script]: Dependency File[my_expect_script] has failures: true
warning: /Stage[main]/Base/Exec[run_my_script]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

The first two execs works fine though (remove yum and add yum)

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think you need to add another directory in /etc/puppet/modules/raj, namely a files directory. Set the myexpect.sh in there and I would expect it to work.

Comment: @TimStoop Thanks a ton for the response, that worked great. If you can please add an answer, so that i can accept (would be useful for others too).

Comment: So, i did 2 things: 1) Added the `files` directory like Tim mentioned `/etc/puppet/modules/raj/files/myexpect.sh` and next is, i changed the `path` in file class to `path => '/tmp/myexpect.sh` because seems like `ensure` expects the path to the full file where it should ensure to be present, if not it creates.

Comment: I had that up as an answer, but apparently a moderator thought it wasn't worth it, without explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Stoop (who pointed it out in comment).
So whenever you add a file in some location and add the source, you need to put them inside the "files" directory, **and more importantly the files directory should not be named in the sources.**

Like my source is: `source => "puppet:///modules/raj/myexpect.sh"` so the actual file needs to be in `/etc/puppet/modules/raj/files`

This is mentioned in the puppet doc: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/modules_fundamentals.html#files

(I had missed it completely until @Tim Stoop pointed above in the comments.

Next is, the path in the `files` module was incorrect. You need to put the entire path including the filename there. Using `ensure => 'present'` the puppet makes sure the file is present there, if not it creates it.

Hence: path => `/tmp/myexpect.sh` is correct.

The entire correct manifest is below:

```
SLES11SP4-118:~ # cat /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
node default {
   include base
}

node 'sles11sp4-170.dev.insiteone.com' {
 class {'base':}
}

class base {
   exec { "remove yum":
   command => 'zypper removerepo 1',
   logoutput => 'true',
   path    => '/usr/bin/'
   }

   exec { "add yum":
   command => 'zypper addrepo -f http://10.156.14.121/repo/RPMS/QA/ QA',
   logoutput => 'true',
   path    => '/usr/bin/'
   }

  file {
    'my_expect_script':
      ensure => 'present',
      source => "puppet:///modules/raj/myexpect.sh", # Make sure file is in /etc/puppet/modules/raj/files
      path => '/tmp/myexpect.sh',
      owner => 'root',
      group => 'root',
      mode  => '0744',
      notify => Exec['run_my_script'],
  }
  exec {
    'run_my_script':
     command => '/tmp/myexpect.sh',
     refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```